# Ubuntu 17.10: Where is Caffe installed?

Tags: caffe, apt, nvidia-digits

The package Digits requires an environment variable to be set with the location of Caffe install directory.

The simple way to install Caffe is `apt-get install caffe-cuda`.  However, I can't figure out where it is installed.  It is not installed in the home directory, and `dpkg -L caffe-cuda` shows only a few files in `/usr/share/doc`.

Any ideas?

Comment: which caffe, what does this command returns?

Comment: which caffe returns /usr/bin/caffe.  I set CAFFE_ROOT to this location and still get the error that Digits cannot find a valid caffe installation.  This file persists even though I apt-get remove caffe-cuda.  Seems like I'm going to have to do a build of caffe in my home directory.

Comment: how did you install digits? you should use the apt-get install digits too

Comment: https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/digits-5.0/docs/UbuntuInstall.md#troubleshooting

Comment: I did not use apt-get for Digits.   The install link sets CUDA_REPO_PKG for which there is a package for Ubuntu 17.04. see http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/.  However, for setting ML_REPO_PKG there is no Ubuntu 17.04.  See http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/.  So I don't know what to do.

Comment: have you tried...16.04,it might be compatible!i`d suggest to install them the same way since they will take care of global variables like $CAFFE_ROOT if you use apt get

Comment: I just trie 16.04 and had a lot of errors.  Will wait till they get a 17.04 version available.  In the mean time, I got the docker digits running.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The following command may help you:

`find / -name "*caffe*"`

The result on colaboratory is not allowed by stackoverflow to paste here,
because stackoverflow mistake it by code.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are installing `caff`e through `sudo apt-get install all` the binaries and libraries will be put to default locations and the `caffe` path will be added. Now, u can use caffe through cmd directly from any directory.

Hope it helps!!